# Prevent images from being edited and retouched

Tags: image, operating-system

I’m trying to make a script that prevents images form being open in photo manipulation software like Photoshop or PaintShop between others.

The idea is to let user visualize images in web browsers or visualization desktop apps in most common OS systems and share or do what ever they like to do with them, but prevent the images form being edited and retouched by the user.

Do you think it is posible and what technology will you recommend me to do this?

Comment: Can't user just take a screenshot of this image and edit it?

Comment: Yes I'm sure it will be imposible to make some thing like this unhackable, but the idea of all of this is do it even if is posible to by the user skip the editing limitation. Is more like concept.